# How can I print / debug all available fields of a data source resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Let's say I have the following Terraform script:

```
locals {
  provisioned_product_vpc_name = "provision-vpc-product"
}

resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "provisioned_product_vpc" {
  name = local.provisioned_product_vpc_name

  template_body = "<foobar>"
}

data "aws_cloudformation_stack" "product_vpc" {
  name = local.provisioned_product_vpc_name
  depends_on = [aws_cloudformation_stack.provisioned_product_vpc]
}
```

How can I interactively see all the fields that `aws_cloudformation_stack.product_vpc` has including the values. At the moment I have to manually open the AWS console and look for the correct values there.

Or is this not possible

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are few ways. You can just `output` when you deploy:

```
output "product_vpc" {
  value = data.aws_cloudformation_stack.product_vpc
}
```

You can also use TF [console](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/console.html). Once you enter the console you just type:

```
data.aws_cloudformation_stack.product_vpc
```

You can also query the sate directly using [sate show](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/show.html), though this will provide a bit different info then the other ones:

```
terraform state show data.aws_cloudformation_stack.product_vpc
```

But its not clear why would you use data source for that if you can directly access your resource `aws_cloudformation_stack.provisioned_product_vpc` in the same way. No need for data source.

Comment: In my case I need to use the data source because I actually want to access the outputs of the stack that is provisioned by the stack I am provisioning

Comment: one question on the terrform console approach. I need use data block to query data first... how do i query data using terrform console?

Comment: and how to I make the 1st approact -- output block -- work? I have put the output block into the tf file and then run the `terraform plan` command... but nothing happens...

Comment: Make sure to run `terraform apply` if you create or update the definition in your data source, to pull the latest state, and have it appear in `terraform console`, before running the console

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add when making changes to the data sources, to also run `terraform plan` to pull the latest info before running `terraform console`.

Comment: I needed to run `terraform apply`, not just `terraform plan`, to pull the latest state into tf before running the console.